# Megaparsec: nested indented blocks eat too much

Tags: haskell, indentation, megaparsec

I am having trouble with nested indented blocks swallowing new lines. I want to parse a function definition (or rather skip the entire body, func. def. is not necessarily top-level).

Example:

```py
func F() -> void: pass

func m():
  pass

func f(a:= 4, b, c:X) -> Y:
    if a >= 0:
        if b > 4:
            return b
        else:
            return c.y(-b)
    else: return c.y(b)
```

My code:

```hs
pFunc :: Parser Node
pFunc = (try pMultiline <|> pOneline) & dbg "pFunc"
  where
    pOneline = do
      (name, args, ret) <- pFuncHead
      pStatement
      return $ NFuncDef name args ret
    pMultiline = (L.indentBlock scn pMultilineIB) & dbg "pMultiline"
    pMultilineIB = do
      (name, args, ret) <- pFuncHead & dbg "pMultilineIB pFuncHead"
      return $ L.IndentSome Nothing (\_ -> return $ NFuncDef name args ret) body
    body = (try nested <|> void pSomeTillEol) & dbg "body"
    nested = (L.indentBlock scn nestedIB) & dbg "nested"
    nestedIB = do
      pStatement
      return $ L.IndentSome Nothing (const skip) body
```

`pFuncHead`, `pStatement` and `pSomeTillEol` don't consume trailing new lines (only `scn` does, I was using [this tutorial](https://markkarpov.com/tutorial/megaparsec.html#parsing-a-simple-indented-list) as a template).

Ran with `"func m():\n  pass\n\n"`:

```hs
pMultilineIB pFuncHead> IN: "func m():<newline>  pass<newline><newli <…>
pMultilineIB pFuncHead> MATCH (COK): "func m():"
pMultilineIB pFuncHead> VALUE: ("m",[],Nothing)

nested> IN: "pass<newline><newline>"
nested> MATCH (CERR): "pass<newline><newline>"
nested> ERROR:
nested> offset=18:
nested> incorrect indentation (got 1, should be greater than 3)

pSomeTillEol> IN: "pass<newline><newline>"
pSomeTillEol> MATCH (COK): "pass"
pSomeTillEol> VALUE: "pass"

body> IN: "pass<newline><newline>"
body> MATCH (COK): "pass"
body> VALUE: ()

pMultiline> IN: "func m():<newline>  pass<newline><newli <…>
pMultiline> MATCH (COK): "func m():<newline>  pass<newline><newli <…>
pMultiline> VALUE: NFuncDef "m" [] Nothing

pFunc> IN: "func m():<newline>  pass<newline><newli <…>
pFunc> MATCH (COK): "func m():<newline>  pass<newline><newli <…>
pFunc> VALUE: NFuncDef "m" [] Nothing
```

**Why is `pMultiline`, so I guess the `indentBlock`, eating the trailing new lines? How to fix it?**

Comment: It seems pretty reasonable that indentBlock consumes the trailing newlines, because normally you wouldn't want them anyway. I would suggest looking at the source for indentBlock and using it as a guide to write your own version that does what you want.

Comment: @5ndG Yes, you are right, it just follows other megaparsec parsers (consuming white space after). I rewrote my top parser to not use `sepByEnd` on `eol` and instead I am using simpler `many`. So far it seems to work well :).